# How a fixed function can influence orthogonality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series

**Background**

Suppose we have a set of orthonormal basis functions $\{\psi_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of $L^2([0,1])$ (for example trigonometric basis), we know that
$$
\int_0^1 \psi_i(x)\psi_j(x)\,\mathrm dx = \delta_{ij}
$$
where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ when $i=j$, else $\delta_{ij}=0$.

**Question**

I am wondering if it is possible to find a pretty well-behaved function $f(x)$ (for example it is uniformly bounded and continuous over $[0,1]$) such that there exists an $\epsilon >0$ that
$$
\int_0^1\psi_i(x)\psi_j(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx > \epsilon
$$
for all $i\neq j$. That is, a fixed function significantly change the orthogonality of $\{\psi_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$

It does not feel quite possible to me, but I do not know any road towards analyzing this, thank you for your help.

Comment: What about $f(x) = 1/ \psi_i(x)$?

Comment: @MikhailTikhonov that assumes that $\psi(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$, which can't be true if the $\psi_i $ form an orthogonal basis.

Comment: On second thought, maybe it could be true, but there's no reason for it to hold in general.

Comment: As an explicit example, if $\psi_n(x) = e^{in2 \pi x}$ then you can use $f(x)= \sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}2^{-|n|} e^{i2\pi n x}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in general.  For example, consider a basis formed as follows:  Start with $\psi_1(x) = 2\chi_{[0,1/2]}$ and $\psi_2(x) = 2\chi_{(1/2,1]}$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function for $A$ (i.e. it is 1 on A and 0 elsewhere).  These are orthogonal, so they can be extended to a Hilbert basis for $L^2([0,1])$.  Yet for any $f\in L^2([0,1])$ we have $\int_{[0,1]} \psi_1 \psi_2 f dx = \int_{[0,1]} 0 \cdot f dx = 0$

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about the Haar basis. But $\psi_3$ and $\psi_1$ will have overlapping support. Is there a problem?